# IBM Worklight - Unable to invoke adapter procedure from client application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to invoke an adapter procedure from client application. The adapter procedure is working on isolated mode, but it is showing error when invoking it from application.

This is my JavaScript file:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    try{
        WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
            adapter : 'userDB',
            procedure : 'getUser',
            parameter : ['demo', 'demo']
        }, {
            onSuccess : function(res){alert("login Success");},
            onFailure : function(res){alert("login Failure");},
        });
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("ERROR::"+e);
    }
}
```

I am simply put my code in easy way to show my actual error for easy understanding ,this is showing error of catch block:

> ERROR::error:invalid invocation of method
>   WL.Client.invokeProcedure;invalid option attribute 'parameter',...

Answer (score 4):

Like the error message implies, the option attribute `parameter` is invalid. It should be `parameters`, with an **S**.

```
function wlCommonInit(){
try{
WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
    adapter : 'userDB',
    procedure : 'getUser',
    parameters : ['demo', 'demo']
}, {
    onSuccess : function(res){alert("login Success");},
    onFailure : function(res){alert("login Failure");},
    });
}
catch(e)
{
    alert("ERROR::"+e);
}
}
```